# Error handling in asp.net mvc url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, quotes

How to handle links with quotes? For example, http://samplesite.com/Users/"
I want to redirect user to error page, but I see the page with exception.

In every link of the form "http://somesite.com/SomeController/SomeAction/" "
(double quotes at the beginning of path)

**Text of exception:**

*Server Error in '/' Application.
Illegal characters in path.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 
Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.*

I want to redirect user to nice error page.

`<customErrors />` - good, but it is not http error.

Comment: Hi Peter, what is the exception you're seeing? If you can included details of that, we might be better placed to help :) Also what is your route defined as - if it's expecting an int for example, then trying to pass in a string will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable the `<customErrrors />` section, and on 404, redirect to the URL you want to display?  I believe the same mechanism for web forms will work here, not 100% sure though...